# QGIS how do create a polygon with a specific size area in KM2 (Without QAD pluggin)

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I try to create a polygon with a specific size but when I try to use the QAD plugin my QGIS crashes.

Can someone help me to create a random polygon with a specific size without QAD in QGIS 3.22?

Comment: Is this about the geometry, or for symbology purposes only? How close do you need to fit the specified size? Are there any criteria when it comes to the shape of the polygon?

Comment: hi, I need a specific size of 3455014997 m2 and the shape can be a rectangle, the only condition I have is to orientate it to fit in the federal state I am looking at

Comment: I figure there are some states smaller than 3455 km². What should happen in such cases?

Comment: You could manually calculate the size of the shape you need (e.g. a square with sides 58779.4m) and then use the Advanced Digitizing panel to draw a polygon to those exact dimensions by specifying the x and y coordinates of each point. You can then move and orientate the polygon as required.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I just did a square very approximately the same size...